# Escaping $ORIGIN for libtool based project

Tags: linux, gcc, linker, libtool

For projects that don't use libtool I have successfully set `RUNPATH` with
`LDFLAGS="-Wl,-rpath='\$$ORIGIN/../lib64',--enable-new-dtags"`. However, for libtool based projects I get `RIGIN/../lib`. Is it possible to use a single `export` compatible with/without libtool? Or will I have to detect if libtool is being used?

```
bash-4.3# readelf -d ../tmp/bin/grep

Dynamic section at offset 0x43028 contains 18 entries:
  Tag        Type                         Name/Value
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libc.so]
 0x000000000000001d (RUNPATH)            Library runpath: [$ORIGIN/../lib]
 ...
bash-4.3# readelf -d ../tmp/bin/awk

Dynamic section at offset 0x9b028 contains 18 entries:
  Tag        Type                         Name/Value
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libc.so]
 0x000000000000001d (RUNPATH)            Library runpath: [RIGIN/../lib]
 ...
```

EDIT:
Correction, I am using `-Wl,-rpath="'\$$ORIGIN'"/../lib,--enable-new-dtags`

Comment: The `[RIGIN/../lib]` looks like a blown make variable of some sort. It's the sort of effect I would expect if one did this in a makefile: `ORIGIN = whatever` and then did `$ORIGIN` instead of `$(ORIGIN)` or didn't properly escape the `$ORIGIN`, which I guess is what you're seeing. You may need an extra level of escape, but I think you'll have to experiment. Would `\$\$ORIGIN` be universal? Try that for libtool to see if it works, so you have a starting point.

Comment: `\$\$ORIGIN` makes both `RUNPATH`s `[RIGIN/../lib]`.

Comment: I have seen some mentions of using a gcc specfile. I am unfamiliar with these. Will libtool use it?

Comment: The only specfile I'm familar with is for rpm [or other package] managers. Do you know the final line in the libtool output make for the ld? Also, I'd look at it to see what it does to/with LDFLAGS. Maybe you need to go the other way and for libtool do `\$ORIGIN` and see. What you want is the recipe that works for libtool [you've got the non-version already]. Then, at worst, it's a conditional hook. libtool may want to own LDFLAGS, so you might have to set another var like: EXTRA_LDFLAGS or some such, that it will use, but leave unmolested. I think you'll just have to keep hacking on it a bit.

Comment: If you do `info gcc`, then search for `spec file` and it will give you some info. But, I'm not sure how it helps. At a guess, it's more for controlling cpp, ld, etc that are invoked by gcc than something like libtool that invokes gcc

Comment: A hack is to accept expansion and make it idempotent. `O=$$O` for make, `ORIGIN=\$ORIGIN` for the shell, etc.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same exact problem when trying to set LDFLAGS for autotools configure script. Setting it like this worked for me:

```
LDFLAGS="-Wl,-rpath,'\$\$ORIGIN/../lib' -Wl,-rpath,'\$\$ORIGIN/../usr/lib'"
```

During the build it translated to libtool arguments as follows:

```
/bin/sh ../../libtool  --tag=CC   --mode=link gcc  -Wall -I/usr/include/openssl ...<skip>... -lrt  -Wl,-rpath,'$ORIGIN/../lib' -Wl,-rpath,'$ORIGIN/../usr/lib' -o libcrypto_backend.la  libcrypto_backend_la-crypto_cipher_kernel.lo libcrypto_backend_la-crypto_storage.lo libcrypto_backend_la-pbkdf_check.lo libcrypto_backend_la-crc32.lo  libcrypto_backend_la-crypto_openssl.lo
```

Since I had to call ./configure script from another wrapper makefile LDFLAGS variable in it looked even more interesting:

```
LDFLAGS="$(OS_LDFLAGS) -Wl,-rpath,'\$$\$$ORIGIN/../lib' -Wl,-rpath,'\$$\$$ORIGIN/../usr/lib'" ./configure ...<skip>
```